# How do I change the color of two UIButtons when I press them?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uicolor

I am trying to use two buttons to toggle between an animated sliding view. When the UIView loads, I want button1 to be UIColor.darkGrey and button2 to be UIColor.lightGrey. Then, when I press button2 I want button2 to become UIColor.darkGrey and button1 to become UIColor.lightGrey. If I press button1, I want button1 to be UIColor.darkGrey and button2 to be UIColor.lightGrey.

It seems simple; Using the storyboard, I connected a UIButton for button1 and button2 as an outlet. Then I connected each as actions. In each of the actions, I included the following code:

```
@IBAction func button1Action(_ sender: UIButton) {
    button2.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    button1.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1){
        self.side1.constant = 0
        self.side2.constant = 0
        self.sideA.constant = 400
        self.sideB.constant = -400
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
@IBAction func button2Action(_ sender: UIButton) {
    button1.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    button2.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1){
        self.side1.constant = -400
        self.side2.constant = 400
        self.sideA.constant = 0
        self.sideB.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }


}
```

When I press button1, everything works as expected; However, whenever I press button2 both buttons are UIColor.lightGrey. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I would simplify your logic a bit and utilize some of the stuff you get "for free" to manage the buttons' states. Gimme a few mins and I'll slap something together.

Comment: Do not try to mess with `titleLabel?.textColor` like that. That is not how to change the color of a button.

Comment: what became of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get some methods "for free" with buttons to manage their state. One of them is `isSelected`. Another is the `tag` property, so you can figure out which button is which. Since you've only got two buttons, you can get away with just using `isSelected` to figure out which is which. You can also use computed `vars` to make your life easier. With those things in mind, here's one approach you could utilize to managing the buttons' states:

1. Declare a `buttons` computed var, like so

   ```
   @IBOutlet var firstButton: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet var secondButton: UIButton!

   // computed var to access your buttons
   private var buttons: [UIButton] {
       return [firstButton, secondButton]
   }
   ```
2. Set up your buttons in `viewDidLoad`.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       // one setup to configure each button for selected or not selected
       buttons.forEach { button in
           button.setTitleColor(.darkGray,
                                 for: .selected)
           button.setTitleColor(.lightGray,
                                 for: .normal)
       }

       firstButton.isSelected = true
   }
   ```

`func setTitleColor(_ color: UIColor?, for state: UIControl.State)` will remain in effect for the lifetime of the button, so you don't need to fiddle with it after the initial declaration (unless you want to change the button's behavior later).

3. One `@IBAction` for both buttons and utilize the `tag` property to figure out which one is which. Since you've only got two buttons, I'm just using `isSelected`. Here's what your single `@IBAction` would look like:

   ```
   @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

       UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
           // flip buttons
           self.buttons.forEach { button in
               button.isSelected.toggle()
           }

           if self.firstButton.isSelected {
               // tweak your constraints for firstButton.isSelected == true
               // tweak your constraints for secondButton.isSelected == false
           } else {
               // tweak your constraints for firstButton.isSelected == false
               // tweak your constraints for secondButton.isSelected == true
           }

       }
   }
   ```

Based on your current implementation, you'll need to right click on the `UIButtons` on storyboard and nuke the existing `IBAction` connections and reconnect both buttons to the method above.